# pasar datos de la vista al controlador con JavaScript ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Estoy metiendome un poco con javaScript, y tengo el siguiente inconveniente.

Con el código script paso una foto desde la webcam, y eso lo hace perfectamente,
pero necesito pasar también la variable "coduser", dentro del mismo script.

¿Cómo lo puedo modificar para que siga funcionando y además obtener la variable “coduser” del *input*?

JavaScript

```javascript
<script language="JavaScript">
    function take_snapshot() {           
        Webcam.snap(function(data_uri){
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
            '<img src="' +
            data_uri +
            '"/>';
            Webcam.upload(data_uri,
                'Capture',         
                function(code, text) {
                    alert('Photo captured');
                });
        });
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```html
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Camera
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="my_camera"></div>
            <form method="post">
                <label class="form-label" for="form1Example23">Codigo Empleado</label>
                <input type="text" maxlength=5 name="coduser" id="coduser" autocomplete="off" />
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Take Snapshot" onclick="take_snapshot()"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Captured Photo
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="results">Your captured image will appear hear...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controlador

```csharp
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Capture(string name, string coduser)
    {
        try
        {
            var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
    }
//......................demás codigo
```

Comment: Eliminé la frase "ya que el anterior no quedó claro.", pues no se entiende a qué _anterior_ te refieres y, en realidad, la referencia no hace falta para explicar esta pregunta. Si hay una pregunta _anterior_ que sea relevante para el contexto, sugiero [edit] e incluir un link a dicha pregunta. Para más información, mira [ask].

Comment: cree una consulta pero estaba confusa, asi que borre y cree una nueva con todo el código

Comment: En StackOverflow puedes [edit] la pregunta y, de hecho, es normal hacerlo para _mejorarla_ hasta que logres explicar el problema de manera que alguien pueda responderte, por lo que no hace falta _borrar_ una pregunta para mejorarla. Un saludo.

Comment: De hecho, había hecho varias correcciones y mejoras a tu pregunta y veo que deshiciste mi edición. ¿A qué se debe eso?

Comment: hola @jachguate,
no tengo idea de cómo deshice las correcciones, supongo que todavía no entiendo bien el sitio.

Comment: Alguien me podría ayudar con mi consulta, o necesitan más información de lo que necesito?

Comment: Dado que dices que fue sin intención, revertí a mi última revisión, para que los cambios que hice queden allí. Puedes hacer clic en el link que dice _"editada hace xxx"_ para ver el historial de revisiones y los cambios que hay entre cada una de ellas.

Comment: Ya encontré como pasar el dato, se puede hacer dentro del mismo link, muchas gracias

Comment: En la parte inferior, coloca la respuesta que soluciona tu pregunta, de ese modo serás el héroe de más usuarios que tengan la misma situación o una similar. Luego de 24 horas marca la respuesta como aceptada para mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos.